# executing bash's complex find command in python shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am new to python. I am trying to execute a bash script in python to extract the count of different file extensions.
I tried the following command

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("sudo find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 ":" $1}'", shell=True)
```

But it throws a syntax error.
On executing find command in bash shell

```
sudo find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 ":" $1}'
```

output will be as follows

```
png:3156
json:333
c:282
svg:241
zsh:233
js:192
gz:169
zsh-theme:143
ttf:107
cache:103
md:93
```

So how can i get the same output in python code? what is the correction required in my current approach?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use triple quotes on the outside like `"""sudo..."""`?

Comment: The `awk` part should be something like `awk '{print \"{\" $2 \":\" $1 \"}\"}'`. It seems like you got unescaped double quotes inside double quotes.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1
    direct_output = subprocess.check_output("sudo find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print "{" $2 ":" $1 "}"}'", shell=True)
                                                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: does the error still occurs without "sudo" ?

Comment: @GuillaumePaniagua: yes no difference by removing 'sudo'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running bash commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Comment: Try with: `output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Many thanks!!

Comment: If you have a named, say, `foo.*`, `echo ${0##*.}` is going to print a list of files in the current directory -- and the behavior of a file named `foo.-n` is entirely undefined. `printf '%s\n' "${0##*.}"` is much reliable -- adding quotes to suppress string-splitting and globbing, and using `printf` rather than `echo`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thanks for the correction!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments any double quote in a string quoted with double quotes needs to be escaped with a backslash:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("sudo find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 \":\" $1}'", shell=True)
```

Single quotes inside a double quoted string do not have any special meaning (except directly at the beginning), so that doesn't allow you to avoid escaping.

The fine details are explained under the header [String and Bytes literals from the Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

As mentioned in the comments another option, which is probably easier to read, is to use triple double quotes:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("""sudo find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 ":" $1}'""", shell=True)
```

While this answers the question, for ease of reading and maintainability I suggest to replace it instead completely with Python, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: You are awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

By the way, you could try to do the same thing in pure Python.
Here is a minimal code that does it:

```
import os

def count_all_ext ( path ):
    res = {}
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ):
        for f in files :
            if '.' in f :
                e = f.rsplit('.',1)[1]
                res[e] = res.setdefault(e,0)+1
    return res.items()


print '\n'.join( '%s:%d'%i for i in count_all_ext('.'))
```

OK, it's very long compared to the Bash snippet, but it's Python...

Comment: Thanks @Captain'Falm ..... Was expecting bash script to run in python!!

Comment: Yep, sorry... it's strong than me, I always try to script in python (instead of platform dependant shell)

Comment: I'd certainly consider this a better approach than the amalgam of tools glued together badly. (Clarifying "badly" -- properly used, `awk` could do the job of `sort` *and* `uniq` *and* the shells running the parameter expansion, etc; using 5 independent pieces instead of one is a sign of not knowing how to use the one well).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for helping in deciding proper approach !!

Comment: @Captain'Flam: since bash asking super user privilege python approach is working fine!!
As i am new to python i was unable to understand the line:
`print '\n'.join( '%s:%d'%i for i in count_all_ext('.'))`
please explain join method here!,Thanks in advance

Comment: Since it's not a good place for teaching python, I suggest you to read more python tutorials, especiallyand consider these samples that may enlighten you : `print '-'.join( i for i in ['spam','and','eggs'])` ;  `print '+'.join( '(%d)'%i for i in (1,2,3,4,5))` ; `a_tuple = (1,'spam',3,'eggs')` ; `print '%d %s and %d %s'%a_tuple` ; `a_tuple_of_tuples = (('spam',3),('and',8),('eggs',5))` ; 
 `print '*'.join( '%s(%d)'%i for i in a_tuple_of_tuples )`

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment : definitely not a good place for code sample... But, in python tutorials : [read especially about `str.join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) and the [string formating operator `%`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) (try the **try it** button).